# How to access the childnodes based on the name attribute in python

Tags: python, xml, dom, xpath

```
<xml>
    <student name="raj" dept="MCA">
        <info>sdfsdf</info>
        <course><sub>maths</sub><sub>english</sub></course>
        <degree><m>80</m><m>90</m><m>100</m></degree>
    </student>
    <student name="sathish" dept="BE">
        <info>sdfsdf</info>
        <course><sub>science</sub><sub>english</sub></course>
        <degree><m>70</m><m>90</m><m>100</m></degree>
    </student>
    <student name="stephen" dept="BTech">
        <info>sdfsdf</info>
        <course><sub>computer</sub><sub>english</sub></course>
        <degree><m>40</m><m>90</m><m>100</m></degree>
    </student>
</xml>
```

Code:

```
def getXmlElementData(xmlfilename, node, attr, name, element):
    collection = getXmlCollectionData(xmlfilename)
    nodes = collection.getElementsByTagName(node)

    for node in nodes:
        if node.hasAttribute(attr) and node.getAttribute(attr) == name:
            info = node.getElementsByTagName(element)[0]
            elementValue = info.childNodes[0].data
            return elementValue
```

In this example I could access the info value by passing the node and attr name.
But how can we access the sub and m elements by passing the xpath
Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you written so far, and what xpath expressions have you tried?

Comment: I am writing common code to access the node data. For examaple: If I want to access the sub. Then I need to pass the attribute raj and course then that will return the course data as list or array. So far I have done  to access the data of direct node values of student. If I hard code we can access everything inside the node using for each. But here i need to pass the path exactly to access the element values based on the attribute name

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- otherwise it looks like you are just trying to get someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: did you get the problem? @i alarmed alien

Comment: The code I am writing is not particularly for one xml it is applicable for all  i need to pass the node then need to get the result based on the node and attribute passed

Comment: At the moment you're just using standard DOM functions, not xpaths. Have a look at the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support and then try recreating your query as an xpath.